# How to pass an SQL function on bulk insert query in node

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, mysql2

I have to execute an INSERT INTO query using mysql or mysql2 in node.js
The values passed into the query utilizes a spatial geometry function `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON()` on `geoMap` column which is of type `GEOMETRY`.

Here is the simplified code:

```js
const insertQuery = `INSERT INTO maps (name, geoMap) VALUES ?`;
const insertData = [];

geoMapList.forEach((geoMap) => {
  insertData.push([
    geoMap.name,
    `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(${JSON.stringify(geoMap.map)}, 2)`
  ]);
});

this.connection.query(insertQuery, [insertData]);
```

The above code does not work and throws the error
`Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field`

I believe this is because the `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON()` is not parsed as a function but as a string by MySQL.

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put MySQL function calls in the parameter array, that data is all treated as literals.

Call the function in the SQL, with the JSON string as its parameter.

I don't think you can use `node-mysql`'s bulk-insert for this, though, so you'll need to insert each row separately.

```
const insertQuery = `INSERT INTO maps(name, geoMap) VALUES (?, ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(?))`
geoMapList.forEach((geomap) => 
    this.connection.query(insertQuery, [geomap.name, JSON.stringify(geomap.map)])
);
```

To avoid calling `query()` thousands of times, you can put multiple `values` lists in the  query.

```
const values = Array(geoMapList.length).fill('(?, ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(?))).join(',');
const insertQuery = `INSERT INTO maps(name, geoMap) VALUES ${values}`;
const params = geoMapList.flatMap(({name, map}) => [name, JSON.stringify(map)]);
this.connection.query(insertquery, params);
```

Since this will create a very long `INSERT` query, make sure you increase the MySQL `max_allowed_packet` setting. You can also split `geoMapList` into smaller batches, rather than doing everything in a single query.

Comment: Okey. Thanks. But isn't it very inefficient as there could be thousands of records.

Comment: I've updated the answer showing how you can create a single query to do them all.